# Reasons behind naming in easy-to-confuse Python's classes such as OS and SYS?

Tags: python, security, operating-system, naming, language-history

I have noticed that considerably amount of questions in SO, relating to Python, are about people messing up Sys -class, OS class and no class. For example, an easy confusing is the case: `os.open("something")`, `open("something")` and `sys.open("something")`. I haven't understood yet the reasons behind the naming of classes, perhaps it is just an evolution.

1. I would like to hear `why` they were created with their current names?
2. Are naming due to things like having FDs in a class?
3. Is naming because some classes require special privileges?
4. To which extent is the naming a design solution?

If you cannot answer the question, feel free to suggest some good mnemonics to memorize the classes and to differentiate them.

Comment: There's no "class" for the built-in `open` function.  It's a function.  Not a member of a class.  It's called a built-in function in the Python documentation.  Here's the list: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#built-in-functions  Please revise your question to use the proper name, otherwise it will be hopelessly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in functions are things that you need often. You do not have to import any module to access them, and thus don't use any module prefix either. `open()` is one such function, since opening files is a very common operation. It opens a file and returns a file object, which is easy to use.

The `os` module is for operating system interfaces. `os.open()` is a raw interface to the file interface of the operating system. It opens a file and returns the bare file descriptor, which you do not normally need for anything.

The `sys` module is for system-specific things. `sys.open()` does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

> Easy confusing is lies in the case: os.open("something"), open("something") and sys.open("something").

A "mnemonic" is the documentation, available on-line or downloaded to your workstation.

- Built-in `open`: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open  "Open a file"
- `os.open`: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.open "This function is intended for low-level I/O."
- `sys.open` doesn't exist.
- `io.open`: http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.open "in Python 3.x it is the default interface to access files and streams"

The "mnemonic" is easy.  Use the one that matches your requirements.

> why they were created with their current names

To keep clutter out of the language an in separate libraries.

> Are naming due to things like having FDs in a class?

Probably.  FD's are an OS feature, not a language feature.  That's why they're in a separate library.

> Is naming because some classes require special privileges?

Not at all.

> To which extent is the naming a design solution?

To keep clutter out of the language an in separate libraries.

Comment: @hhh: Please delete the "New question analyzing just rings" comment.  It is confusing because it is not related to this answer or this question at all.  Please delete it.

Comment: It investigates statements such as `"This function is intended for low-level I/O."` and privileges. I think it is too much for this question, better for a new question. Sorry but I want to understand what your answer really incur. Are the low-level things rings or something else? It is not clear yet. The question analyzing deeper them [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603239/how-can-i-access-ring-0-with-python).

Comment: @hhh: Please try to focus.  One question or the other.  Try to avoid links between questions in comments.  "Low-level" in this context has nothing to do with any "rings".  "Rings" are just permissions.  Nothing more.  Here, "low-level" means OS-level ("low") or Python library level ("high").  Low-level == OS level == raw OS open/close/read/write == no Python parsing or buffering == byte-level I/O.  High-level == Python library == Python parsing and buffering == Python strings.